# `pdftex-def` obsolete - When updating MikTeX, I can't compile

Tags: pdftex, compiling, updating, update

When I updated MikTeX through the automatic update program, I could not compile afterwards. It could not find pdftex-def. I then uninstalled MiKTeX and reinstalled it again. Now it is working again. If I run the update program again, I can see that pdftex-def is obsolete and will be removed. Is that was caused the problem in the first place? Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: there should be a package graphics-def that has pdftex.def and several other def files that you can install. This was supposed to be an "invisible" re-organisation of some files in the distribution (to fit with current maintainers) but it seems that the move from pdftex-def to graphics-def isn't always as automatic as we hoped:-)

Comment: Let MiKTeX Updater remove it, and install via MiKTeX Package Manager (if not proposed by the Updater) `graphics-def`.

Comment: Should I just update MiKTeX again, and not expect the same problem occurs again? `graphics` is being updated to 1.0s (15-jul-2016).

Comment: When packages are reorganized you should synchronize your offline package database https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: OK - I go ahead again and automatic update MikTeX, and after that, manual install graphics-def in PM. Will post the result here.

Comment: Thanks, it is fine now, I did not had to manually install graphics-def. Should I delete my question?

Comment: @TobiasDK other people may have same problem, why not self answer, saying what you did.

Comment: Ok, will do that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean install of MiKTeX solved the problem. Now I can run the automatic update via MiKTeX which automatic remove `pdftex-def`from MikTeX, without any problems.

Edit: as pointed out by  Ulrike Fischer, I did not need to make a clean install of MikTeX, just find the missing package and install that in the package manager.

Comment: Reinstalling miktex is not necessary. You only need to run the standard administration tools, like synchronizing, checking for new packages in the package manager and running the update manager. I had a missing pdftex.def too after one of the last updates and it took me only 5 minutes to get it.